# fluent ffmpeg => how to trim and concate parts of video into one output file without writing many output files. Make a most efficient solution

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-processing, fluent, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm currently working on a online video website and i need to make a quick preview of videos using random timestamps and duration of the video.

Suppose the video is of 15 min then  i want to cut out some parts like ->

```
1. from 00:00:40 take out next 2s 
2. from 00:01:20 take out next 2s 
3. ... and so on until the new video becomes 15s
```

How can i do this with **fluent-ffmpeg** in the nodejs project

Can i get the most efficient way of doing this **without writing many output files and then concating them separately and removing then later**

Only concating the trimmed videos in one output file and save when it is done.

I also came through a solution that uses complex filters but i don't know how to use it

````js
   ffmpeg("video.mp4")
  .complexFilter([
    ....// some filters here

  ])
  .on('end',  function () {
    console.log('files have been merged and saved.')
  })
  .on('error',function (err){
    console.log(err)
  }
  .saveToFile("output.mp4")```
````